# When the Pontryagin square is an even class?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, spin-geometry, cohomology-operations

Let $n$ be an even integer and $X$ a manifold. Given a cohomology class $B \in H^k(X,\mathbb{Z}_n)$, the Pontryagin square is a class $\mathfrak{P}(B)\in H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{Z}_{2n})$. Is it true that if $X$ is a spin manifold then $\mathfrak{P}(B)$ is an even class? In this case it should make sense to consider the class $\frac{\mathfrak{P}(B)}{2}\in H^{2k}(X,\mathbb{Z}_n)$. What is the most general class of manifolds where this makes sense? Could you provide an example where this does not make sense?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{P}(B)$ is an even class, then wouldn't $\frac{\mathfrak{P}(B)}{2} \in H^{2k}(X, \mathbb{Z}_{\color{red}{2n}})$?

Answer (score 6):

If $B \in H^2(X;\mathbb{Z}_2)$ satisfies $B^2 \neq 0$, then $\mathfrak{P}(B) \in H^4(X; \mathbb{Z}_4)$ is not even as $\mathfrak{P}(B) \equiv B^2 \bmod 2$. Such classes can exist on spin manifolds, for example, take $B$ to be the generator of $H^2(\mathbb{CP}^3; \mathbb{Z}_2)$.

If $X$ is a closed $2k$-dimensional manifold and $B \in H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$, then $B^2 = \nu_k\cup B$ where $\nu_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ [Wu class](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wu+class). So if $\nu_k = 0$, then $B^2 = 0$, so $\mathfrak{P}(B) \equiv 0 \bmod 2$, i.e. $\mathfrak{P}(B)$ is even for every $B \in H^k(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$. When $X$ is a closed four-manifold, then the relevant Wu class is $\nu_2 = w_1^2 + w_2$. In particular, if $X$ is spin (or more generally, pin$^-$), we see that $\mathfrak{P}(B)$ is even for every $B \in H^2(X; \mathbb{Z}_2)$.

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was looking at the case of $H^2$ for four-manifolds. This clarifies how it works in general. About the question I asked on the reduction to $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ (that you mentioned in the comment), I would say that an even class can be consistently divided by $2$, and the result is well definite modulo $n$. Differently said you have the SES $\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2$ where the right map is $\text{mod}(2)$ and even elements are in the kernel of this map, so they are lifted to elements in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I am assuming your answer does hold for any $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with $n$  even, not only for $n=2$. Am I right?
Also, can you suggest a reference where the story you described is explained? (I think it is textbook material at the end, but I am a physicist...)

Comment: I don't know how things work with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficients. One key fact about $\mathbb{Z}_2$ coefficients is that $B \mapsto B^2$ is linear, so it can be given by the cup product with a fixed class; this is not true for other coefficients. There is an analogue of the Wu class for odd primes though, see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268331/generalize-wu-formula-to-integral-cohomology-classes#comment663391_268331). Regarding a reference, I have [some notes](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~m3albane/notes/wu.pdf) on Steenrod Squares and Wu classes that you may find helpful.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the Pontryagin square with $\mathbb{Z}_n$ coefficients? I am familiar with the case where $n$ is a power of $2$, and when $n$ is a power of an odd prime, there is a Pontryagin $p^{\text{th}}$ power. There is a generalisation to arbitrary coefficients, but I'm not sure that's what you mean. See [this page](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Pontryagin_square) for details.

Comment: The Pontryagin square, at least on 2-cocycles, can be defined with coefficients in an arbitraty finite abelian group $A$. It takes a class in $H^2(X,A)$ into a class into $H^4(X,\Gamma(A))$, where $\Gamma(A)$ is the universal quadratic group. For instance $\Gamma(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ for odd $n$, and to $\mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ for even $n$.